# Removing Salsa flavor from vegetable soup

Tags: soup

I was making homemade vegetable soup. I had used 2 pint jars of home-canned tomatoes then accidentally added a jar of home made salsa. My daughter hates salsa so what can I do to take away some of the salsa taste. I don't like how it tastes right now either and it also has too much salt. Any idea what I can do now to fix my mistake?

Comment: Without knowing the contents of the homemade salsa, as well as what else you had put into the soup. it is hard to help you. Seeing as you yourself do not like the flavor, I would suggest that you may be best off cutting your losses and dumping the soup.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you may want to consider starting over. You have 2 big problems, and you could end up spending a great deal of time (and ingredients) trying to fix it and end up with something twice as big and just as unpalatable.

If you really want to do it the salsa part is easy: cook it. What many people don't like about salsa is raw flavors, they will mellow quite a bit with the application of heat. If you don't tell your daughter then chances are she won't even know!

The real problem is the salt, once you add it there's no sure-fire way to get it out. If something is very salty the only thing you can do is add ingredients that aren't salty in order to even out the salty flavor. You could make another vegetable soup with no salt and then mix the two, or add some water to your soup and see if that fixes it.

If it isn't too salty I have had some success using potato to absorb some of the salt. Potatoes are good at soaking up salt flavors, you can add some cup up potatoes in and once they are cooked take them out and some of the salt comes with them. Or if you find that the combination works leave them in.

So what I would do is if it's not too far gone would be to add some unsalted stock or water, and then some cut up potatoes. Cook it until the potatoes are tender, then taste. If it's acceptable then serve it with a smile, if not throw it away and chalk it up to experience.

Answer (score -2):

I am going to get told off for this answer because I have no references for it and being on my phone it will take me a while to find a reliable source but here goes.

To take away the salty taste just add sugar. This isn't just a 'salty and sweet flavours are opposite' reasoning but there is science behind it. The salt and sugar binds together to form different taste molecules which reduces the salty flavour. Like I said, I don't have a link to evidence this but it is something I have been doing for years and have been told by a reliable source that this is the why it works.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that it only addresses the saltyness, not the (for lack of a better word) salsaness, of the soup.

Comment: The other problem is that it doesn't address the saltiness. A mixture of sugar and salt doesn't stop tasting salty, it tastes sweet and salty at the same time, which is worse than just oversalted.

Comment: I didn't answer that part because I don't have an answer for it, I thought it best not to guess. I am going to disagree with you rumtscho, this is not the case at all. The sugar reacts with the salt to reduce the saltyness, it won't just add a sugary taste.

Comment: Unbelievable someone would come up with this answer.

Comment: Please lay out your rebuttal of this answer Blessed Geek.

Comment: The OP might be objecting to the amount of salt in the soup for health reasons---adding sugar won't help with that.